# Why isn't "are" correct?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, existentials

The sentence is:

> There is a mountain and a lake.

I thought this sentence was wrong. But I was told it is correct. I just, I don't know. Shouldn't it be "are"? Why is "is" correct? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Same issue, this is a duplicate.

Comment: @Nihilist_Frost Hold on old chum, it's a what? In what sense are mountains and lakes uncountable? In what sense are rice or meat countable? How are these duplicates?

Comment: Go argue with the five people who closed...

Comment: @Araucaria That's why I asked, it isn't duplicate. I looked that question but I couldn't get my answer.

Comment: @Nihilist_Frost If you leave a comment, expect other comments!

Comment: I recently edited my answer to the question linked above.  Let me know if you still feel it doesn't also answer your question.